# Deletion banner by underage deleted user displays the original username

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts

On [this deleted Arqade question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/212090/i-need-ideas-and-feed-back-on-this#comment287032_212090) (10k only, of course), the user self-deleted the question, then their account was deleted for being underage. The account name displays as "user106595" in the question and comments, but the deletion banner says "deleted by <original username> yesterday." It should say "deleted by user106595 yesterday."

Comment: I don't think the username is something SE is required by law to remove, but it easily could be problematic in cases where a user younger than 13 uses their real name as a user name

Comment: Even if removing it is not legally required, displaying the name inconsistently seems like a bug.

Comment: That does seem to be basically the same thing, but it's over 2 years old and it doesn't seem to have any official response

Answer (score 3):

Ah, that's by design, I guess. The notices (closure, deletion, lock, merge, protect, etc?) *always* save the original user names, while the name in the comments and user cards in the posts don't (also used to do it at very first).

I'm even kinda get used to it.

<sub>Exception: when the question is migrated and the OPs of the question and answers doesn't have an account, the user card displays the original user name, not `user<id>`.</sub>

---

And *just by the way*, while we are at this point, there isn't the only inconsistency: the edit suggester if deleted is displayed as "anonymous user", a reviewer if deleted gets its review vote attributed to Community. That's just how the things work, and, how strange it wouldn't be, I don't see anything strange there.